# Web Addin Support in comparison with VSTO/COM based Extensions for PowerPoint

Tags: plugins, vsto, powerpoint, office-js, office-addins

I am trying to build a Powerpoint Addin using the new JS-based stack that Microsoft has introduced. As part of the development, I am evaluating the support that the current JS libraries are providing. While VSTO/COM-based plugins have been around for quite some time, lack of cross-platform support is a challenge(especially for Mac and now Web), which is also the reason I want to opt for Web-based Addin(JS). But Powerpoint doesn't have a HOST API as Excel or Word does which makes things slightly challenging.

Thus here are the capabilities I want to have from the JS stack -

- Ability to add and change the properties of shapes. While adding a shape doesn't have a specific API function, I was able to add it as an SVG object. Is there an easier way to change the properties of shapes and
- Adding links to shapes to different slides.
- Initiating other office apps like Excel and the ability to edit/read data from those instances.
- Apply Slide Transitions.
- Ability to connect other data resources through a URI.
- Store state of shapes and slides.

It would be great if someone can point to the appropriate sections of the documentation which might help me find answers to this.

Answer (score 0):

Most of what you are requesting cannot yet be done in a PowerPoint Web Add-in. But you can so some of it; for example, "connect to other data sources through a URI". I recommend that you look through the Develop section of the documentation.
[image]